# Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use interested_time.set() instead

Tags: django

I'm trying to implement multiple singup form with django all auth. It is working fine for the first form because first form doesn't contain any type of many to many relationship. In case of second form it contains lots of many to many realtion ship. I'm new to django and allauth, I didn't know how to handle this problem.
some of the code snippets is given below.
[image]

models.py

```
class JobSeekerProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, verbose_name=_("User"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    religion = models.ForeignKey(Religion, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    interested_area = models.ManyToManyField(ServiceArea)
    interested_time = models.ManyToManyField(WorkingShift)
```

forms.py

```
class JobSeekerSignupForm(SignupForm):

    full_name = forms.CharField(
..........
    )

    interested_area = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        required=True,
        error_messages={'info': 'Interested Area is required'},
        label="Interested Area",
        choices=[[0, '']] + [[r.id, r.title] for r in ServiceArea.objects.all()],
        widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={
            'id': "inputGroup1_17",
            'class': select_input_class,
            'style': "width: 100%;",
            'data-placeholder': "Interested Area ",
            'data-open-icon': "fa fa-caret-down",
            'data-close-icon': "fa fa-caret-up",
        }),
    )


........

    def save(self, request):
        user = super(JobSeekerSignupForm, self).save(request)
        user.is_job_seeker = True
        job_seeker = JobSeekerProfile(
            user=user,
            full_name=self.cleaned_data.get('full_name'),
            interested_area_set=self.cleaned_data.get('interested_area'),
            ........
            interested_time=self.cleaned_data.get('interested_time'),


        )
        user.save()
        job_seeker.save()
        return user
```

and views.py

```
class JobSeekSignupView(SignupView):
    template_name = 'user/job-seeker-signup.html'
    form_class = JobSeekerSignupForm
    redirect_field_name = 'next'
    view_name = 'jobseekersignup'
    success_url = None

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ret = super(JobSeekSignupView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ret.update(self.kwargs)
        return ret
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly assigne value (record(s)) to M2M field. Here are the [examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

Instead of this:

```
interested_time=self.cleaned_data.get('interested_time')
```

first save JobSeeker and then use `add()` and then add record via M2M:

```
job_seeker.save()
job_seeker.interested_time.add(cleaned_data.get('interested_time'))
```

Comment: TypeError at /user/job-seeker/signup/
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/user/job-seeker/signup/

Comment: What's in `cleaned_data.get('interested_time')`? A list of objects? If yes, then simply change add second line to `job_seeker.interested_time.add(*cleaned_data.get('interested_time'))`